# Spring-data-mongodb intercept query and inject predicate or specification

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Environment:

spring-data-mongo: `1.7.0.RC1`
mongo-java-driver: `3.2.2`

Document:

```
@Document(collection = "products")
public class Product  {

    @Id
    private String sid;

    private String name;

    private Long vendor;

    (...)
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

    Product findByName(String productName);

}
```

My goal is to intercept any query performed on the Product collection and add a predicate or a specification without modifying the repository or the need to implement the method findByNameAndBelongsToVendorList.

I need this interceptor or aspectJ because I have multiple methods like:

```
Page<Product> findAll(Pageable page);

List<Product> findByCategory(String category, Pageable pageRequest);

(...)
```

**Goal**

```
findByName // perform a filter by name (explicit) 
           // and a filter by vendor (injected via inteceptor or aspecJ)
```

**Avoid doing this**

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepositoryCustomImpl implements ProductRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate template;

    public Product findByNameAndBelongsToVendorList(String name, List<Long> vendors, Pageable pageRequest) {

        Criteria criteriaVendor = Criteria.where("vendors").in(vendors);
        Query query = new Query(criteriaVendor);
        query.with(pageRequest);

        return template.findOne(query, Product.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aspects should do the trick.

```
@Aspect
public class YourAspect {

  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate template;

  @Pointcut("execution(public * findByName(..))")
    private void findByName() {
  }

  @Pointcut("within(com.leonel.repository.ProductRepository)")
  private void repository() {
  }

  @Around("repository() && findByName()")
  public Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
      Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
      String name = (String) args[0];

      Criteria newCriteria = YOUR NEW LOGIC HERE;
      Query query = new Query(newCriteria);

      return template.find(query, Your.class);
  }
```

I would recommend against it though, as it introduces a bit of magic to your code and manipulating queries should not be a concern of aspects.
What is the reason you want to avoid having multiple *find* methods in your repository?

Comment: Currently I use 2 frameworks ... SpringData e MongoTemplate. With MongoTemplate I can use an pointcut on *org.springframework.data.mongodb.core* and intercept all methods like findAll, findOne ... but with SpringData I don't know yet how to do that.